# Are DRY questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Asking "give me teh codez" type questions are frowned on, but what about questions that blindly ask us to refactor their code for them?  The question titles rarely contain any useful keywords (eg. DRY up my [insert language name here]) and as a result, they really only serve the OP.

Such questions *might* be a good fit for CodeReview if they were phrased differently and didn't also contain broken code.

Examples:

- [How do I DRY up this script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248176/how-do-i-dry-up-this-script)
- [Best practice, good patterns to avoid DRY violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513823/best-practise-good-patterns-to-avoid-dry-violation)
- [how to dry up sass mixin code with before and after blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498142/how-to-dry-up-sass-mixin-code-with-before-and-after-blocks)
- [How could I compress/optimize this code (jQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837144/how-could-i-compress-optimize-this-code-jquery)

Many of the questions that appear under the [dry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dry) tag are also quite opinionated.

Related meta topic on CR:  [Are reviews that ask us to DRY their code within the spirit of CR?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/are-reviews-that-ask-us-to-dry-their-code-within-the-spirit-of-cr)

Comment: I'd think, "Can this code be smaller?" isn't a specific enough question. I also don't think it's fair to ask, "What's a better way of doing this?" when the question is actually, "What's the *correct* way of doing this?" because the code doesn't actually work.

Comment: Most of the time, the code does work, but I did see a few that contained broken code (eg. the OP tried to DRY up their code but now it is broken).  Candidates for moving to CR *must* contain working code.

Comment: Some questions of this kind should be migraded to [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: In case you came here from a duplicate or similar, the acronym stands for "Don't Repeat Yourself".  In other words, these are questions about refactoring or optimizing repetitive code.

Answer (score 39):

Just like we are not a *code writing service* (ie. give me teh codez), we are not a *code optimization service*.

That said, DRY or other code improvement requests *could* be on topic if the problem they are trying to solve is absolutely clear and not overly broad.  Most of the questions I looked at in the DRY tag were too broad and should be closed as such.

## Goofus and Gallant

These questions might be asking for the same thing:

- Can my HTML/CSS get smaller?
- Can CSS image replacement be done without using an extra element?

or

- My Sass seems really repetitive
- How can I generate classes that only vary by tacking a number onto the end?

The first question is vague and could be applied to thousands of code reduction requests (and there may be other issues with the code other than the fact that they're using more markup than they need).  The second is clearly trying to tackle a single, specific problem.

- Optimize my parser
- How can I make my string parser's execution time linear rather than exponential?

## So Yes, but...

The question *should be able to stand on its own* as a specific problem.  Wishy-washy "show me how to make it less repetitive" questions should be downvoted for showing a lack of effort/research (or possibly closed as being too broad).

- Did you try using a linter?
- Did you try anything to make it less repetitive?  (eg. write a loop or an extra function)

If you have trouble trying to do this on your own, make sure that when you ask your question that it focuses on resolving your failed attempt rather than asking for your code to be refactored (eg. *I tried to do X, but got error Y*).  Oh, and always make sure you search to make sure your question hasn't already been asked/answered before.

Comment: Oh how I wish the users that have posted/will post DRY question would be able to read this meta post. However, chances are they wont :(

Comment: @Keale: you could always link them to it in a comment ;)

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**. All these askers are dealing with a *specific programming problem* that they need help with. That's totally in the scope of SO.

As [that MCR question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5404/13522) you dug up states, these kinds of questions are equally on-topic at CodeReview. And if they were more generic questions like "*How do I tackle [this kind] of ugly repetitive code in [framework|language|situation XY]?*", they might even be on-topic at Programmers as well.

Admittedly, many of those questions are badly written and deserve downvotes. "Gimme teh codez" is not acceptable, and questions that show a lack of understanding (like when not knowing loop statements) deserve to be downvoted.
One can write very good questions about DRYing code that show prior research (what techniques are available) and include the attempts at applying those techniques (explaining what the problems in the process were met or how the result is still not satisfactory). Those of course are rare.

Comment: (I'd like to hear an opposition statement in a *No*-answer :-)

Comment: What is and is not off-topic goes beyond whether something is a "specific programming problem".

Answer (score 5):

DRY questions (as normally stated) are not on topic for Stack Overflow.

We're a site dedicated to useful programming knowledge.  While DRY questions typically embody 'programming' and 'knowledge', they're far less useful than they need to be to a wider internet audience.

Here's why:

"DRY" questions typically have a title that isn't useful to your every day Googler (Our audience, as it turns out):

Take [this title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625909/how-would-i-make-this-racket-code-dryer):

> How would I make this Racket Code DRYer?

There are a grand total of two words in that title that have any google juice: "Racket" and "DRY" (hoping google is smart enough to discern DRY from dry).

So we have an immediate problem: Anyone who has a similar issue to the OP won't be able to find their answer.

Then we get into the meat of the OP's problem:

> The problem is that it's not very DRY. Since I'm using a Lisp, and Lisp is known for being able to do crazy things, I want to know if there's a way to take all the subprocess code and extract it so I can do something like: (code removed)

Again, no google juice here.  That means that the problem will likely not be found by other people on the internet, which is a core tenet of Stack Overflow: Whatever question you pose needs to have utility for others.

It's the "If a tree falls in the forest" problem: If no one can find your question when they have the same problem, it needs to be edited or closed until it's improved.

DRY questions typically have these problems; I just took this example because it's the newest iteration I saw.

[DRY questions as a whole are inherently un-googleable](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20make%20this%20code%20DRY). As such, they should be off topic (our old close reason "too localized" would have been a good fit for this):

[image]

Code Review was made for such questions; they've specifically focused on improving code; whereas those types of questions are ostensibly about programming, but not useful to others unless they're written really really well.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it might be on topic for the Code Review area. Nowhere else, I think.

Comment: That's not really much of an answer.

Comment: As far as i can tell, it's the correct answer. There is an appropriate place on SE to ask for advice on how to improve code's structure. Migrating these questions there seems to be in complete, exact conformance with SE standard practice.

Comment: Except most of the questions asked here are not suitable for migration to CR.  They have very strict standards for quality over there, and the questions I saw do not fit that.

Comment: In that case, the "nowhere else" seems to come into play, unless the question is restructured in a way that makes it a good fit somewhere

Comment: Yes, they might be on topic on CR. But why would they be off-topic on SO?

Comment: Because code review questions *are* offtopic on SO, by long accepted practice. If folks have specific questions about specific parts of their code, that's in SO's scope. If they just want to know how they can improve their coding style with no specifics, that's been ruled out of scope. If everyone wants yo change that you're free to do so, but you'll have to spend time and effort reeducating the SO community.

Comment: @keshlam: Yes, *unspecific* questions are off-topic (nearly everywhere as "too broad"). But questions that ask about specific [tag:dry]ing techniques seem to be accepted on SO since long (there's over 1200 questions in that tag, only [32 of them](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdry%5D+closed%3Ayes) being closed).

Comment: Ok; I'm willing to be outvoted on that.

Comment: @cimmanon regarding migration, being suitable for migration and being on-topic are two separate things. Nearly all "code optimization" questions here actually should be asked on Code Review. Yes, the quality of nearly all of *those* questions is such that they'd be closed there. But they should be edited and made high-quality questions *there*, not here. Re-asked, if need be.

Comment: @TylerH - SE has a rule about not migrating garbage. If a site attempts to migrate a question to another SE site and that site considers it off topic or low quality, that site can reject it. At least, that's how it's been explained to me. I think that makes sense; there's not real reason to move a question that just needs to be closed.

Comment: So are we concluding that it's just a Bad Question and should be closed? I'm fine with that too.

Comment: @BSMP I think you misinterpreted my comment. I wasn't advocating for migrating off-topic posts.

Comment: @keshlam - I was agreeing with cimmanon that if a question doesn't meet the quality standards at the target site then it should just be closed rather than attempting to migrate.