# Feature request: add blurb about Code Review in "How to Ask"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, code-review-se

Right now, when someone creates a new question on SO, they see the "How to Ask" box with the following:

> **Is your question about programming?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.

Often with "newer" users, I see questions about a working chunk of code, but requesting some form of help refactoring. While the question *is* about programming, there is no specific issue that could help a future user. There are many ways to refactor code, and usually the code that OP provides is too unique to help others viewing the question.

Example, now migrated to Code Review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957161/age-classification-how-can-i-improve-this-code

I do not want to flag the question for being off-topic. The question has positive votes, it has an answer, and the answer has positive votes as well. The answer is also very in-depth, and looks to bring a "code review" question more in the scope of SO, by introducing new methods in Go to OP. It is definitely a resource to learn from.

I understand that the sites listed for migration are based on how frequent that site receives SO-migrated questions. Currently, Code Review is not on the list *but* always has the chance to be. Therefore, I am not suggesting that we make Code Review a permanent choice there.

I think something along the lines of the following would be good for the "How to Ask" box:

> **Are you looking for critique, advice on refactoring, or best practices?**
>
> Do you already have working code?
>
> You may want to ask your question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

I decided to link to the on-topic article, because it will immediately handle OP's issue of where to post his question.

Comment: For info, the people over at Code Review [don't like it](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) when a question is closed as off topic with a reason of "it belongs on CR".

Comment: Most questions that *might* be more appropriate on CR generally are not suitable for CR due to the fact that they're low quality.  Related:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295665/are-dry-questions-on-topic

Comment: No one that needs to will read it. If they had bothered to read any of the other material placed there they wouldn't be posting that type of question anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea.

Consider that the current box is 4 lines. You're asking to add 3 more for our **fifth** migration target (10k users can see migration stats), while only **one** other migration target is already mentioned (and that's Meta, which is special). Those numbers just don't add up.

In other words - this would show a non-trivial amount of information to everyone even though this information is only relevant to a very tiny minority (those asking Code Review questions).

I don't think even a single line would be worth the screen space - the more we add, the less chance there is that it will be read, so we really want **only** the vital information there, not anything that could occasionally apply.

Although I do think the *How to Ask* box could do with a rewrite (and the whole page could be reworked - *How to Format* probably takes up way too much space) - perhaps we could say something like "describe your problem in detail", which is a link to a page that briefly mentions Code Review.

Comment: I suspect that people would either read zero **or** 7 lines!

Comment: @DavidG But adding more encourages more people to read 0.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan You may be right, I was just making the (cynical) point that people either read most/all or none regardless of how much content there is.

Comment: @DavidG I agree with the cynicism that most will read none or all, I just definitely think that the amount will influence that to an extent.

Comment: I agree with a rewrite and redesign of the page. Not many people read the "how to format". Especially since SO has a pseudo-WYSIWYG editor, there is no need for it on the desktop site. (IDK how it is on mobile or app.)

Comment: @HunterStevens I wouldn't say the formatting is particularly intuitive, but I don't mind fixing formatting issues, where-as I **can't** fix problems like insufficient information or an incomplete code sample myself.

Comment: To complement what you're saying: this change would affect *all users* asking a question, but would only be relevant to a very tiny minority (those asking CR questions). I think doing something similar to what we do for the [tag:code-golf] tag might make more sense (showing a message when you use said tag), but there might be some implications I haven't thought of.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Yes, but what tag would you use?  A lot of the questions I see don't use any specific tag other than the language tag.  Some use DRY.

Comment: @cimmanon `code-review`. I realize this wouldn't catch *all* the code review questions (some don't have the tag), but at least we can be confident there won't be too many false positives (i.e. showing a message to someone that is totally irrelevant to them). Not saying there aren't other solutions, but I wouldn't be as confident implementing them without data showing they wouldn't result into many false positives.